# Trying to implement Facebook Conceal method for saving encrypted password but didn't work?

Tags: facebook, cryptography, password-encryption, facebook-conceal

Trying to implement facebook conceal to save encrypted passwords, i removed all errors and android app runs but as i used insert method in Registration so when i click the registration button the app stops working. Before adding the crypto code the app was working fine and was saving passwords.

```
    public boolean insert(String email, String password, String uName, String pNo){
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Crypto crypto = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(this,CryptoConfig.KEY_256),
            new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary(), CryptoConfig.KEY_256);
    byte[] cipherText =null;
    try {
        cipherText = crypto.encrypt(password.getBytes(),entity);
    } catch (KeyChainException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CryptoInitializationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Email", email);

    String finalString = null;
    try {
        finalString = new String(cipherText, "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    contentValues.put("Password", finalString);
    contentValues.put("UserName", uName);
    contentValues.put("PhoneNumber", pNo);
    long ins =db.insert("userTable", null, contentValues);
    if(ins==-1) return false;
    else return true;
}
```